# Is WordPress considered a PHP web framework?

Tags: php, wordpress, web-frameworks

Is WordPress considered a PHP web framework?

Comment: No. Its an opensource Blog application many bend to their will in order to make it do more.

Comment: Yes, but what does it matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wordpress wouldn't really be considered a framework, but more of a CMS allowing the user to build their website on it, but under strict guidelines.

A framework would be more general.

- CakePHP
- CodeIgnitor
- Zend

are frameworks